# mac autocomplete like autohotkey

Tags: macos, autocomplete, autohotkey

I find my self typing often certain words. And I remember there was a cool function in Autohotkey (for PC) that let you type only a few letters of a word and an autocomplete function, completed the word for you.

Is it possible to have the same thing in OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually more of a "how to use OSX" question suitable for SuperUser than the focused programming questions of StackOverflow;

But since I'm here, what you are looking for is the "Text" shortcut feature which you'll find in the Keyboard system preference pane.

It looks like this:

[image: Yosemite Text Shortcut]

Comment: Thanks. It's what I was looking for. I'll check Super User next time. Sorry to all for this.

Comment: I found out that it doesn't work on the application I wanted it more to work: Firefox and Safari : ( I also tried this command on the terminal: defaults write -g WebAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled -bool true but it did nothing

Comment: There's also a commercial package called [QuickKeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/) that might help you out...

Comment: If I installed an app for every cool feature I saw they do, by now I would have a million of apps. I ask here precisely to avoid instaling a thousand apps.